# Using tabs in GNU Emacs 23

Tags: emacs

I have been looking into packages that would enable me to have **tabs** in my emacs editor. Would like to open multiple files in a single emacs window. Any help/link would be appreciated

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Emacs has this functionality built in. They are called buffers `C-x C-f` opens a new file of a name you provide. `C-x b` lets you change between buffers. `C-x C-b` lists all open buffers. `C-x k` closes the current buffer.

If you want multiple buffers in one window then `C-x 2` splits the windows horizontally. `C-x 3` will split it vertically. `C-x 1` will close all the windows that are not the current one. `C-x o` cycles between open panes. &c.

`GNU` the organization that manages the code base for `GNU Emacs` has a wonderful [tutorial](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/tour/)

Note: the the above segment `C-` means while holding the `<CTRL>` key

post script: the [ido](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings) library makes working with emacs in generally much easier.

Comment: To kill the current buffer you should use `C-x k`, not `C-x C-k`.

Answer (score 3):

You can already open multiple files in buffers. However, if you want a visual guide, then this is what you might want: http://emacswiki.org/emacs/TabBarMode

Caveat emptor: You might have to configure it a bit.

Comment: This answers the question but the emacs "way" is to use buffers along with one of the many navigation/selection bindings rather than tabs. Tabs are quite primitive compared to the buffer list anyway.

Comment: You are, of course, correct. However, when faced with questions like this, I prefer to give the OP what they want, and let them figure out the madness of their ways themselves :-)

Comment: @Mario - usually I agree with you. Answer the question asked, not just give the "Right Way (TM)" to do it. That being said, with something like Emacs, where in you can basically do anything you want ( as it's almost an OS in it's own right ) I think it can be forgiven.

Comment: I disagree. The OP asks a question because of a mistaken assumption. Helping him along the wrong way (especially without a caveat) will cripple him.

Comment: In my experience, this usually doesn't "cripple" people. At the worst, it will educate the person when they are annoyed. And as you said, alternatives where already provided, so there was a caveat emptor.

Wrong forum to discuss this, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use [elscreen](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsLispScreen)

and use Gnu/Linux too, so i remap the Winkey to manage my tabs.

Answer (score 0):

emacs doesn't contain "tabs" like an internet browser its best to understand the concept of buffers like the others have said but if you want to have a tab bar at the top anyway just to give a quick reminder of what buffers are open I suggest looking at the [TabBarMode](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/TabBarMode) in the emacs wiki.

When using buffers i like to use `m-x ibuffer` since you can filter out which buffers your interested in. say you only want to see the buffers which are associated with files in a /home/flood/coding/epicgame/ directory, i simple go to ibuffer, type `/ f` then type epicgame and a filter will be applied, then to remove the filter simply press `/` twice and remember that `C-h m` is your friend.

This technique has helped me alot, you can even OR filters together and merge them into groups. I love emacs XD